# 4k external monitor stuck in 1080p

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, 4k

I have Macbook Pro 16" 2019 model. Recently I bought Acer 4k Monitor VG280K.

I'm connecting it to Macbook Pro with HDMI which came with it and attached it with a USB C to HDMI converter which support 4k@60Hz.

I'm facing a very annoying bug. Sometimes randomly Macbook is rendering full 4k and sometimes its rendering only 1080p. I have to restart or replug the cable multiple times for it to render 4k.

I noticed others are also facing the same issue https://piunikaweb.com/2021/02/04/external-4k-monitor-issues-after-macos-big-sur-11-1-update/

I have talked with the Apple Customer Care but they were not helpful.

I'm also using this new monitor with Windows laptop and getting full resolution without a break, so the HDMI cable and monitor is fine.

Thousands of people like me are facing the same issue as mentioned here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252174979

I patiently waited for 11.3.1 update and hoped it might fix it but it didn't fix it. I don't know what to do now. I'm stuck with this problem for months.

Comment: Did you test the "USB C to HDMI converter"?

Comment: Yes, alway try another cable. It's the cheapest option. I know you said it works on Windows, but that in itself is another difference.

Comment: @JBallin No I didn't test that converter. I assumed it's fine because like its mentioned in the other threads the resolution drops only when I restart the Mac or when I replug the cable or close the laptop lid.

Comment: I presume this happens after sleep rather than after a clean boot. Try waking the monitor before waking the Mac. Often this kind of issue is that the display doesn't get its info to the Mac in time.

Comment: @Tetsujin Tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: In the morning I upgraded to Big Sur 11.4 and since then external display is working in 4k. I think this issue is fixed. I will check for a few days and report here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this is fixed with Big Sur 11.4